# How to configure a connection interval in a BLE connection?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I have been using tools (`hcitool`, `gatttool` etc) from the BlueZ bluetooth protocol stack to connect to my BLE device. I have been able to successfully connect to the device and obtain data off it. My application however demands faster transfer of data from the BLE device (BLE peripheral device) to my computer (BLE master device).

One of the ways I can make the connection run faster is by making the connection interval shorter on the main device but I have no idea how to do that in my Linux system.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the connection interval through the hci kernel filesystem interface before starting the connection:

```
echo  6 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_min_interval
echo 20 > /sys/kernel/debug/bluetooth/hci0/conn_max_interval
```